# Linear Independence of Secant-squared or tangent-squared

Tags: linear-algebra

Due to a result from Chowla, we know that the set $\cot(2\pi k/n)$, such that $\gcd(k, n) = 1$, is linearly independent over the Rationals.

Do we have any similar results for $\sec^2(2\pi k/n)$ or $\tan^2(2\pi k/n)$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you just need to use common trig identities to answer this.

Comment: I don't get it...how do I use common trig identities to solve answer this?

Answer (score -1):

K. Wang, On a theorem of S. Chowla, J. Number of theory 15 (1982), 1-4
all the derivatives of cot(x) which includes sec-squared and hence tan-sqared.

Comment: okada, on an extension of a theorem of S Chowla